# Using Bazel to create a (GitHub) release artefact

Tags: bazel

I am trying to adopt Bazel for a project which was recently converted to a monorepo.

(I am VERY new to Bazel and have no mentor handy, please excuse me if the questions I ask are answered with "rtfm"; I am happy to do so, please point me to the manual.)

This monorepo contains a bunch of libs and binaries. When a certain tag is set, the goal is to build everything (as in `bazel build //...`), pack all the binary files into a zip and attach the created archive to a [GitHub release](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases).

I am comfortable with GitHub Actions, triggers and the releases itself, however I am not sure what an appropriate approach would be to create the archive containing all binaries via Bazel. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg

Answer (score 0):

You should go through below links [#1](https://earthly.dev/blog/monorepo-with-bazel/) [#2](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/bazel-build-tutorial-examples), [#3](https://github.com/thundergolfer/example-bazel-monorepo), [#4](https://diego-pacheco.medium.com/monorepos-with-bazel-75b3f336837f).